# How to find Position of Game Object through Script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm very new to unity and I'm making a snake game. The problem is that I have a particle system for when you eat an apple however I want the particle system to go over the apple when you eat it. The way the apple works is it basically teleports to a different location when you "eat" it. So is there a way to take the location of the apple and move the particle system there when you eat an apple? If so how do I do that?

Thanks

Comment: `particleSystem.transform.position = apple.transform.position`?

Comment: I can try that out and tell you if it works! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every GameObject in Unity comes with a Transform component so once you have a reference in to an object in a variable, like so

```
public GameObject yourGameObject;
```

then you can access the transform by

```
yourGameObject.transform;
```

If you want to change the position, for example, to (1,1,1) you can do it with

```
yourGameObject.transform.position = new Vector3(1,1,1);
```

It works in a similar way for rotation and scale.

Unity documentation is pretty good and you should have a look to [Transform](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.html)

Comment: @PuddleProductions If this answered your question [you should Upvote/Accept it.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: The code to change the position is not working. Does anyone know why?

Comment: Because `transform.position` is a [**property**](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties) it doesn't work that way .. rather use `yourObject.transform.position = ....;` otherwise you only change the `Vector3` **returned** by the property's **getter** but never execute the property's **setter** and thus never assign it to the object

Comment: @derHugo don’t know why I wrote it that way. Thanks for spotting it